# Keyboard keeps freezing

Tags: debian, xfce

Every once in a while the keyboard freezes for a bit, but the mouse still works fine.

The keyboard and mouse are connected to the computer via a single wireless dongle.

The problem is fixed by a reboot.

I confirmed that the CPU and RAM were not being fully utilized.

What else might be causing it?

UPDATE:
It seems like it might have something to do with my GPU.
I found this in `/var/syslog` right after an incident:

```
Dec 25 00:28:33 debian kernel: [  920.350428] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-60df4653-7e30-ba1b-17c9-f7a69fcdb14a
Dec 25 00:28:33 debian kernel: [  920.350430] NVRM: GPU Board Serial Number: 
Dec 25 00:28:33 debian kernel: [  920.350432] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 31, Ch 00000034, engmask 00000105, intr 10000000
```

Comment: What distribution are you running, destkop environment/window manger, kernel, etc? Are there any relevant log snippits?

Comment: i'm using buster. Kernel 4.13.0-1-amd64. I don't even know what logs to check!

Comment: Start with `dmesg` output and `/var/log/syslog`, maybe `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, and try to capture them around the time of the incident. You could open a couple terminals and follow them with `tail -f` (and `dmesg -w`). Also keep in mind that issues like this may be more likely since you are on a testing release of Debian.

Comment: I added a few lines of the syslog to the OP.

Comment: It's unlikely (but not impossible) that the delay is caused by the GPU in some way. Assuming it's an USB dongle, the event path is: USB -> dongle driver -> kernel input layer -> X/Wayland input layer. Test systematically where the problem is: First check the kernel input layer (`evtest`, see if you get events even if you don't get keypresses). After that `usbmon`, or `xev` (or whatever Wayland can use).

Comment: That syslog snippet doesn't look very relevant.

Comment: I figured I'd put an update here in case anyone stumbles across this later. I changed the settings for my graphics card using `nvidia-settings` to high performance and the problems went away. Very weird...

Comment: But I did use `usbmon`. Whenever there was an incident, I would see no activity while it was frozen and then I'd see the last few key presses go through all at once when it unfroze.